# What the -f in the "apt-get -f install" command do?

Tags: apt

I know that the -f means `--fix-broken` from the manual and that it attempts to fix problems with the packages, but what exactly does? How it decides how to fix the packages or if they need fixing and the method of fixing? And why sometimes it fails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `--fix-broken`, or `-f` just sets the `APT::Get::Fix-Broken` option to true, but that's not the interesting part. Whenever `APT::Get::Fix-Broken` is true [it sets a bollean](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/apt/apt.git/tree/apt-private/private-cachefile.cc#n64) called `FixBroken` to true which [enables more logic on apt-get](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/apt/apt.git/tree/apt-private/private-cachefile.cc#n94). This logic does two things: it calls the `pkgFixBroken` function which resides in the algorithm.cc file, which should return false and verifies that `BrokenCount()` function returns 0. The later is obvious, if BrokenCount is different of 0 then we have broken packages and have problems, but [the relevant part here is a instance of a `pkgFixBroken` class that gets initialized and then called with the `Resolve()` function.](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/apt/apt.git/tree/apt-pkg/algorithms.cc#n308)

The `pkgFixBroken` method to fix packages is simple, mark all installed packages as upgradeable and marks the packages that doesn't have downloadable version available for fixing. Once this is done, it calls then the `pkgProblemResolver` function (or what it seems to be) which makes things a little complex to follow, but there's a comment that explains more or less what's going on:

> This routines works by calculating a score for each package. The score
>      is derived by considering the package's priority and all reverse 
>      dependents giving an integer that reflects the amount of breakage that
>      adjusting the package will inflict.
>
> It goes from highest score to lowest and **corrects all of the breaks by 
>      keeping or removing the dependent packages**. If that fails then it removes
>      the package itself and goes on. The routine should be able to intelligently
>      go from any broken state to a fixed state.
>
> **The BrokenFix flag enables a mode where the algorithm tries to 
>      upgrade packages to advoid problems.**

That explains more or less things. It assigns scores and tries that from the higher scoring packages, all of them have its dependencies solved.

That seems good enough to fix most of things, except when it doesn't. The reason for this is that Fix Broken doesn't try to "fix" the packages inasmuch as just making sure that all the packages has their dependencies satisfied. In other words if A depends on B and C, it makes sure that B and C are installed before A, and *nothing else*.

The usual reasons for this to fail aren't because unsatisfied dependencies, in the sense that all packages are there and can be, in theory, be installed, but because dpkg, which has another tests, fails. In those cases `dpkg --audit`, `dpkg --configure -a` may give you more information than apt does.

I recommend you to read all the comments and, if you have C++ background, try to read the code in case you need a more thoughtful explanation of what it does.